# Is it possible to use .join() with multi-line strings?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

Suppose I have this multi-line string:

```
s = """
Foo
Foo
"""
```

At first, I tried to use `.join()` to join it together for a result like this:

```
Foo Foo
Foo Foo
```

This is what I did with `.join()`:

```
print ''.join(s for _ in range(2))
```

And this is the result I got:

```
Foo
Foo

Foo
Foo
```

How can I get the ideal result?

Comment: Your string contains a newline between the two times "Foo" is written.  If you just join the string to itself, you'll still have newlines between every "Foo".  Using `join` doesn't change the contents of the string itself, so it won't get rid of line breaks that are inside it.  If you want to get rid of the newlines, you need to remove them yourself, for instance as shown in the answers given by others below.

Comment: First split then join. Or replace newlines.

Comment: You should use a better example, for example one used in wim's solution and post your expected output for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a generic solution will be combination of `zip` and `splitlines`:

```
>>> a = """a0
a1
a2
"""
>>> b = """b0
b1
b2
"""
>>> temp = [x.splitlines() for x in (a, b)]
>>> print '\n'.join(' '.join(x) for x in zip(*temp))
a0 b0
a1 b1
a2 b2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print ('\n'.join([" ".join(s.split()) for _ in range(2)]))
Foo Foo
Foo Foo
```

Comment: The `[]` brackets aren't necessary.

Comment: @SteveJohnson, go and time the code using a list and not using a list, you will see why I did

Comment: what exactly is the downvote for?

Comment: I'm not sure, but probably because this turns the vertical into the horizontal

Comment: I don't know, I thought this was a good solution.

Comment: @wim, how do we know that is not the required behaviour?